# installing php 5.4 as FPM when already installed as apache module

Tags: php

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and i want to install `php 5.4` as `FPM` to use with `Nginx` but i already have `php 5.3.8` installed as `apache module`. I know i can set the `prefix switch` when i configure `php 5.4` as some directory to prevent it from overwriting `php 5.3.8` which is installed in the default path which is `/usr/local/lib/php`. But how can i prevent it from overwriting the php executable in `/usr/local/bin/php` and ini file in `/usr/local/lib`. Also i find that there other directories `/usr/lib/php5` and `/etc/php5`. Would they be overwritten too. If yes how can i prevent them from being overwritten? I want to keep my php 5.3.8 too as an apache module so i cannot just overwrite it.

Comment: Just make a second install in another location, also change the name of the ini file.

Comment: @hakre can i set the name of the ini file during `configure`? if yes then how and what about the executable?

Comment: I can not tell you, but the build script should be able that you can specify diverse stuff. There are installations with more than one version, especially there is some testing framework that allows to install *many* php binaries next to each other, but I don't have the link at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile it from source, you can specify target directory and where to search for ini file:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/php54 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php54/
```

Running `./configure --help` will show you all available options

> But how can i prevent it from overwriting the php executable in /usr/local/bin/php

using prefix, your executables will be placed in `{$prefix}/bin/` and `{$prefix}/sbin/`, so  path to them will look like `/usr/local/lib/php54/bin/php` and `/usr/local/lib/php54/sbin/php-fpm`

Comment: i installed php 5.4 as you said with `--with-config-file-path=/etc/php54`. Now i can see `phpinfo()` in my browser and in the configuration file path it shows `/etc/php54/` but there is no directory as `/etc/php54/` on my filesystem so where is it reading the configuration from? Is it still reading the old configuration file and if yes how can i change it?

Comment: If the directory (or file) doesn't exist, no ini file is loaded (see `loaded configuration file` on `phpinfo()` page ) and php runs on predefined configuration. You should create this directory and copy your ini file there.